# Why my react native navigation header Right is not working fine

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

first of all sorry because I'm new in react native.
I'm trying to create an app with React Native and I have this App.tsx (I'm working with typescript)
Everything is okey when i press the plus icon, I get redirected to "AddVehicleScreen" but here is the problem, when I'm in that screen, the plus button is here too and I only want to show that Icon in the VehicleScreen not in the AddVehicleScreen

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabStack = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home Screen',
          /*tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="home"
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),*/
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="ExploreScreen"
        component={ExploreScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Explore Screen',
          /*tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="settings"
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),*/
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const HomeScreenStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="BottomTabStack" component={BottomTabStack} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const SettingScreenStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="SecondPage"
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="SettingScreen" component={SettingScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const VehiclesScreenStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="VehiclesScreen"
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="VehiclesScreen"
        component={VehiclesScreen}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          drawerLabel: 'Vehicles',
          title: 'Vehicles',
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AddVehicleScreen"
        component={AddVehicleScreen}
        options={{
          headerRight: () => null,
          headerShown: false
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f4511e', //Set Header color
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff', //Set Header text color
        }}>
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="HomeScreenStack"
          options={{
            drawerLabel: 'Home Screen Option',
            title: 'Home Screen',
          }}
          component={HomeScreenStack}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="SettingScreenStack"
          options={{
            drawerLabel: 'Setting Screen Option',
            title: 'Setting Screen',
          }}
          component={SettingScreenStack}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="VehiclesScreenStack"
          options={({ navigation }) => ({
            drawerLabel: 'Vehicles',
            title: 'Vehicles',
            headerRight: () => (
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  console.log('Add vehicle pressed');
                  navigation.navigate('AddVehicleScreen');
                }}
                underlayColor={'transparent'}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={faPlus}
                  size={20}
                  style={{
                    marginEnd: 11,
                  }}
                  color={'#fff'}
                />
              </TouchableHighlight>
            ),
          })}
          component={VehiclesScreenStack}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the plus icon for the entire stack group within the drawer. To resolve this you need to set the header for the needed screen only like this:

```
const VehiclesScreenStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="VehiclesScreen"
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="VehiclesScreen"
        component={VehiclesScreen}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          drawerLabel: 'Vehicles',
          title: 'Vehicles',
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={() => {
                console.log('Add vehicle pressed');
                navigation.navigate('AddVehicleScreen');
              }}
              underlayColor={'transparent'}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faPlus}
                size={20}
                style={{
                  marginEnd: 11,
                }}
                color={'#fff'}
              />
            </TouchableHighlight>
          ),
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AddVehicleScreen"
        component={AddVehicleScreen}
        options={{
          headerRight: () => null,
          headerShown: false
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Hope this help you :D